# Permissions Error querying ReportServer

Tags: reporting-services

I have query in a stored procedure in my database which does

```
SELECT [Name]
  FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog
```

This works fine when I log onto my PC and SSMS using Windows Authentication.

This stored procedure is used in a data set called 'Reports' in a Report.
However, when I launch a browser and navigate to

```
http://localhost/reports/browse/
```

and select that report, I get the following error shown and logged:

```
e ERROR: An exception has occurred in data set 'Reports'. Details: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException: The permissions granted to user 'DOMAIN\user.name' are insufficient for performing this operation.
at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RSServiceDataProvider.CheckAccess...
```

where `DOMAIN\user.name` is my login mentioned above.

All other reports run fine when browsed for this way.

I've tried searching for this error, and despite there being dozens of 'solutions' proposed for this error message, none of them relate to this scenario.

Note that SSMS shows that `DOMAIN\user.name` is the owner of the **ReportServer** database.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving  the `DOMAIN\user.name` the `RSExecRole` membership for the ReportServer database?

If you drill into the Security folder for your ReportServer database in SSMS and right-click on your `DOMAIN\user.name` and select Properties, you should see a `Membership` tab. That is where you will find the checkbox for `RSExecRole`.

**Note:** You will probably have to restart your SQL Server after making this change.

Comment: I have tried that, but I get an error message:
"Cannot use the special principal 'dbo'".
DOMAIN/user.name is named 'dbo' in my SQL Server instance,
as it is the owner of all the databases (db_owner).

Comment: Might be a silly question, but are you running the report from Internet Expolorer and are you running IE as administrator?

Comment: I usually use Chrome, but did try running as admin. Doing so caused it to work OK. As this is on my PC, and for debugging purposes, that is acceptable.

Comment: Personally, I've never had great luck using any browser other than IE for SSRS. If you have the username and password of the user account listed in the Reporting Services Configuration Manager under Execution Account, and can log into the Report Server through a browser with that account, adding your DOMAIN\user.name as an administrator in settings should relieve the problem of you having to run the browser as administrator.